# Что такое сценарий внедрения базы данных?

Tags: база-данных

Процесс создания учебного проекта(программная система) включает в себя задачу "Разработать сценарий внедрения базы данных". 
Во-первых, что такое внедрение БД?
Во-вторых, что за сценарий внедрения?
Буду очень признателен за ссылки, по которым можно почитать по теме, лучше на англоязычные источники

Comment: "infiltration" -- АХХХХАХАХАХАХАХХААААХАХА!!! Кхм. Хм. Извините. "Integration". Зацените [документацию у Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/integrate.1012/b14069/scenario.htm).

Comment: @D-side Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky с радостью б, но больше у меня нет информации по этой теме, а можно ли переводить материал по ссылке, лицензионно неясно. Поэтому это и комментарий.

Comment: Преподаватель ответил на мой  вопрос так: "Сценарий внедрения это набор SQL DDL инструкций, которые необходимы для создания базы данных, ее составляющих (таблиц, представлений, индексов, триггеров, хранимых процедур и.т.д), а также пользователей и возможно базовых данных (DML) необходимых для работы вашего приложения."